# how to load interactive .swf in mobile flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, embed, interactive, mobile-application

i have a mobile application that i am attempting to use to load an interactive .swf file. At first, i was just going to use the .mxml applications from my other project file in flex, but they're for desktop apps and running on Flex 3.6, and Mobile apps can't be built on less than 4.5 :P

so, i figured i'd export the first project to a .swf, and load it in my mobile application, but nothing i do will get it to show up. anyone know a solution?

here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Task Graphic Novels">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:SWFLoader width="100%" height="100%"
                 loadForCompatibility="true"
                 id="bookLoader" enabled="false"/>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import 
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:List height="100%" width="100%">
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:IconItemRenderer height="100" labelField="name" 
                                    iconField="photo" iconHeight="70" 
                                    iconWidth="54" messageFunction="getMessage">
                    <fx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            import spark.components.NavigatorContent;
                            protected function getMessage(o:Object):String
                            {
                                return o.message;
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </fx:Script>
                </s:IconItemRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <fx:Object name="Breach an Obstacle" photo="@Embed('assets/img/sumeco/beach/title.jpg')" message=""/>
                <fx:Object name="Conduct a Raid" photo="@Embed('assets/img/sumeco/title.jpg')" message=""/>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:dataProvider>
        <s:change>
            <![CDATA[
            if(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.name == "Beach")
//here's where i'm trying to load the swf  {bookLoader.enabled=true; bookLoader.load(new U    RLRequest("assets/BookDemo.swf"));}
                else if(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.name == "Title"){}
                ]]>
            </s:change>
        </s:List>
</s:View>
```

Comment: i haven't gotten any errors, it's just not loading :/ as of now, clicking that item does the same as clicking the second one, nothing.

Comment: What platform are you targeting?  It's not possible for iOS.

Comment: not at all for iOS? not even if the swf is included in the packaged application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that'll work since you're trying to load a local swf.  I think it needs to be loaded over the internets, and even so, why are you loading a swf in locally? Why not call to it directly?

Comment: Oh, also, if you're going to go over the net, you need to add the permission.

Comment: how would i call to it directly?

Comment: I believe you can embed it in the source: `<SWFLoader source="@Embed('assets/BookDemo.swf')" />`

Comment: `VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of activate in mx.managers.SystemManagerProxy.

VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.graphics::RoundedRectangle could not be found.

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable _SWFLoaderStyle__embed_css_Assets_swf___brokenImage_113275806 is not defined.

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable BookDemo__embed_mxml_assets_img_sumeco_breach_an_obstacle_title_jpg_1106297139 is not defined.`

Comment: it looks like it's looking for the resources from the original files i compiled the swf from?

Comment: seems like it.  You'll need to either embed those as well in the swf you're trying to load